# Деление без остатка

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Как найти `X`, при котором `(A + X * B)` будет делиться без остатка на `C`?

Для примера: `A` = `17`, `B` = `199`, `C` = `11`

`(17 + X * 199) % 11 = 0`

Как найти X в приведенном примере?

Comment: Начать с А=А%С; B=B%C; а потом тупо подбор.

Comment: А можно ли чисто аналитически решить? Формулой.

Comment: https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E

Comment: Та-а-ак, формулой. Вы, конечно, понимаете, что решений здесь бесконечное множество?

Comment: Это понятно. Необходимо найти хотя бы одно решение.

Comment: @Igor, вообще-то решение единственное в кольце вычетов. По крайней мере, если модуль простой и умножаем не на 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё считаем по модулю 11:

```
17 + X * 200 = 0
6 + X * 2 = 0
X * 2 = -6
X * 2 = 5
X = 5 / 2
```

Обратный элемент для 2 равен 6 (поскольку 2 * 6 = 1)

```
X = 5 * 6
X = 30
X = 8
```

http://e-maxx.ru/algo/reverse_element

[Нахождение обратного элемента в кольце вычетов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/613603/178988)

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать как рассчитать обратный элемент в общем виде?

Comment: @Denis, есть описание по ссылке и есть [теорема Эйлера](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_(%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)). Ну и бинарное возведение в степень можно посмотреть.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант - перебором:

```js
function solve(a, b, c) {
  for (var x=0; x<c; ++x) {
    if ((a + b*x) % c === 0) {
      return x;
    }
  }
}

console.log(solve(17, 199, 11));
```

Comment: Ищу вариант чисто аналитического решения. Перебор не подходит.