# Нахождение обратного элемента в кольце вычетов

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика

Необходимо найти элемент **`B`**, обратный элементу **`A`** по модулю **`C`**.

Такой, что `(A*B)%C = 1`.

Как найти **`B`** в общем виде?

Comment: а А - известен? по идее: `(1+C)/A`

Comment: Да, A известен. Но элемент B долже быть целым числом.

Comment: А что ему может помешать быть целым числом? В принципе формула выше - это частное решение, общее, что-то вроде `(1+N*C)/A`

Comment: Но ведь тогда добавляется неизвестная N

Comment: Потому что решений = бесконечное множество. Можно даже на примере: _A=4, C=5. B=(1+N*5)/4=1/4+N/4+N. При N=3 - 1/4+3/4+3 = 4._ Проверка: `4*4%5=16%5=1` При N=15 `1/4+15/4+15=19`. Проверка: `4*19%5=96%5=1`

Comment: Необходимо любое из решений в пределах от 1 до C

Comment: Ну так все то же самое: получаешь формулу и перебираешь `N`, которое тоже целое число наверное, пока результат не будет в указанных границах

Comment: А можно как-то обойтись без перебора? При условии, что все числа целые.

Comment: а чем не нравится перебор?

Comment: Числа большие, перебор неэффективен получается

Comment: Какой порядок чисел?

Comment: Видимо в пределах от 1 до D, а не 1 до С?

Comment: @AK, откуда D взялось? :-) и почему ты поправил на _найти **наибольший** элемент_ - вроде любой надо

Comment: @Grundy я так понял из вашей переписки. Раз есть возражения -- ок, откатил, пусть сам автор вносит изменения в свой вопрос.

Comment: Ну я же вчера ссылку давал: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/reverse_element

Comment: @AK как следует из курса математики, в диапазоне от 1 до C может существовать не более 1 решения. Поэтому слова "наименьший" и "наибольший" - лишние.

Comment: связанный вопрос [разбить число на сумму произведений его составляющих](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/732818/23044)

Answer (score 13):

Смотрите.

Для начала, `A` и `C` должны быть взаимно просты. Если они не взаимно просты, то любая линейная комбинация `(A * X) % C = A * X + C * Y` не будет равна единице, то есть, ответа нет.

Окей, пускай числа `A` и `C` взаимно просты. Для установления этого вы должны использовать алгоритм Евклида для вычисления НОД. Если вы при этом воспользуетесь [*расширенным* алгоритмом Евклида](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), вы получите не просто НОД, а и те коэффициенты `alpha`, `beta`, при которых

```
alpha * A + beta * C = НОД(A, C) = 1.
```

При этом `alpha` и есть ваш ответ, так как

```
(alpha * A) % C = (1 - beta * C) % C = 1.
```

Все остальные значения `B` получаются из данного прибавлением кратного числу `C`.

Comment: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/export_extended_euclid_algorithm

Comment: Да и вообще: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/reverse_element

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51859/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd------).

Answer (score 5):

Есть два пути для решения этой задачи.

### Путь первый - использование расширенного алгоритма Евклида.

Алгоритм Евклида ищет НОД двух чисел. Расширенный алгоритм Евклида одновременно с этим представляет НОД как целочисленную линейную комбинацию исходных чисел:

```
Ka∙a + Kb∙b = (a, b)
```

Как легко заметить, если A и C не являются взаимно простыми, то решения нет, а если являются - то коэффициент при A и будет искомым обратным элементом (для доказательства можно заменить в формуле выше b на C и взять обе части равенства по модулю C).

Рекурсивный алгоритм довольно прост. На очередном шаге большее из двух чисел (для определенности, a) представляется как `c + k∙b`, после чего алгоритм вызывается рекурсивно для `(b, c)`:

```
Ka∙(c + k∙b) + Kb∙b = (a, b)
Ka∙c + (Kb + Ka∙k)∙b = (c + k∙b, b) = (c, b)
Kc1∙c + Kb1∙b = (c, b)
```

Отсюда имеем Ka = Kc1 и Kb = Kb1 - Kc1∙k

Получаем примерно такой алгоритм:

```
ФУНКЦИЯ НОД(a, b) -> (d, Ka, Kb):
    ЕСЛИ (b == 0) ВЕРНУТЬ (a, 1, 0)

    (d, Kb1, Kc1) = НОД(b, a % b);
    ВЕРНУТЬ (d, Kc1, Kb1 - ⌊a/b⌋ ∙ Kc1);
```

Итеративный алгоритм столь же прост в реализации, но сложнее в понимании. Проще всего использовать матрицы. Для начала, следует записать преобразование коэффициентов в матричном виде:

```
                     | 0    1  |
(Ka Kb) = (Kb1, Kc1) |         |
                     | 1 -⌊a/b⌋ |
```

Эти матричные множители можно будет накопить:

```
|K11 K12|   | 0     1  | |K11` K12`| 
|       | = |          | |         | 
|K21 K22|   | 1  -⌊a/b⌋ | |K21` K22`|
```

Получается следующий алгоритм:

```
ФУНКЦИЯ НОД(a, b) -> (d, Ka, Kb):
    K = (1, 0)(0, 1) // Начинаем с единичной матрицы

    ПОКА b > 0
       K = (K[1, 0], K[1, 1])(K[0, 0] - ⌊a/b⌋∙K[1, 0], K[0, 1] - ⌊a/b⌋∙K[1, 1])
       (a, b) = (b, a % b)

    ВЕРНУТЬ (a, (K[0, 0], K[0, 1])
```

Теперь, когда у нас есть НОД, осталось найти НОД(A, C), проверить что он равен 1 и взять (Ka % C) в качестве искомого обратного числа.

Время работы - порядка log A по основанию φ итераций (это связано с тем, что худший случай для алгоритма Евклида - соседние числа Фибоначчи).

### Путь второй - использование формулы Эйлера

Если число C заранее известно, или есть достаточно времени на подготовку, то можно воспользоваться формулой Эйлера:

```
A ^ φ(C) = 1 (mod C) для взаимно простых A и C
```

Поскольку для имеющих нетривиальные общие делители A и C задача решения все равно не имеет - ограничение нам не помешает.

В соответствии с формулой, ответом будет `A ^ (φ(C) - 1) % C`. Быстро найти его можно при помощи алгоритма быстрого возведения в степень:

```
ФУНКЦИЯ СТЕПЕНЬ (a, x, c):
     b = 1

     ПОКА x > 0:
       ЕСЛИ x - НЕЧЕТНОЕ, ТО 
         x = x - 1
         b = (b * a) % c
       ИНАЧЕ
         x = x / 2
         a = (a * a) % c

     ВЕРНУТЬ b
```

Корректность этого алгоритма легко доказывается если заметить что `a ^ x * b` - его инвариант.

Разумеется, после получения ответа надо будет проверить что он правильный, если он будет неверным - значит, ответа вовсе не существует (A и C имеют общие делители).

Этот алгоритм будет работать быстрее чем алгоритм Евклида, потому что тут основание логарифма больше, а сами итерации - проще. Но для применения этого алгоритма требуется заранее знать φ(C)

Answer (score -1):

Реализация расширенного алгоритма Евклида на Python.

```
def M(A,N):
    B = 1
    C = 0
    D = A % N
    E = N
    while D > 1:
        F = E/D
        G = C - B*F
        H = E - D*F
        C = B
        E = D
        B = G
        D = H
    return B % N

X = 7
N = 199

Y = M(X,N)
print Y
```

`Y` - искомый обратный элемент для `X` в кольце вычетов по модулю `N`.

Comment: Ужесть. *Надо было еще while записать как W, а print - как P!*

Comment: Не вижу такой ужести по вашей ссылке.