# разбить число на сумму произведений его составляющих

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, математика

Есть число, например `111`, так же есть ещё 2 числа `3 и 5` на которые число `111` должно разделиться без всяких остатков и прочего...
может быть не совсем правильно словами объясняю, вот пример как это должно выглядеть:

```
21*5+2*3 = 111
```

Я не могу сформулировать нормально для своего понимания как это должно выглядеть словами, не то чтобы написать конкретный алгоритм =)
собственно кто может объяснить сам принцип? хотя бы математически как то это расписать....

Comment: какие из вариантов Вас устраивают: `21*5+2*3, 18*5+7*3, 15*5+12*3, ...`?

Comment: Существует алгоритм нахождения простых делителей числа. Думаю, стоит вам с ним ознакомиться...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Решение в целых числах [диофантовых уравнений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) вида `a⋅x + b⋅y = c` можно свести к поиску [коэффициентов Безу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D1.8D.D1.84.D1.84.D0.B8.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82.D1.8B_.D0.91.D0.B5.D0.B7.D1.83).

Если `x`, `y` решения уравнения `a⋅x + b⋅y = d`, где `d = gcd(a, b)`, тогда решением исходного уравнения будет пара: `с₁⋅x`, `с₁⋅y`, где `с₁ = c / d`. Отсюда:

- если `c` не делится на `gcd(a, b)`, то целых решений нет
- начальное решение можно найти используя [расширенный алгоритм Евклида](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83#.D0.92.D1.8B.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D1.8D.D1.84.D1.84.D0.B8.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D1.81_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.89.D1.8C.D1.8E_.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC.D0.B0_.D0.95.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B4.D0.B0)
- имея начальное решение `(x₀, y₀)`, можно найти бесконечное количество решений по формуле: `(x₀ + k⋅u, y₀ - k⋅v)`, где `k` произвольное целое, а `u`, `v`:

  ```
  u = b / gcd(a, b)
  v = a / gcd(a, b)
  ```

`gcd(a, b)` это [наибольший общий делитель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C). Если решение есть, то существуют такое решение `x`, `y`, что [`abs(x) < abs(u)` и `abs(y) < abs(v)`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83#.D0.9C.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.80.D1.8B_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D1.8D.D1.84.D1.84.D0.B8.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2).

Используя [код для нахождения коэффициентов Безу из вики](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0):

```js
/// find integer x,y such that a*x + b*y = gcd(a, b)
function find_bezout_coeff(a, b) {
  var p = 1,
    q = 0,
    r = 0,
    s = 1,
    x, y;

  while (a != 0 && b != 0) {
    if (a >= b) {
      a = a - b;
      p = p - r;
      q = q - s;
    } else {
      b = b - a;
      r = r - p;
      s = s - q;
    }
  }
  if (a != 0) {
    x = p;
    y = q;
  } else {
    x = r;
    y = s;
  }
  return [x, y];
}

/// find integer x,y such that a*x + b*y = c
function solve_diophantine(a, b, c) {
  var [x, y] = find_bezout_coeff(a, b),
    d = a * x + b * y; // gcd(a, b);
  if (c % d != 0)
    return "no solution";

  // solution: (c*x+k*b)/d, (c*y-k*a)/d for any k in Z
  var c1 = c / d;
  return [c1 * x, c1 * y, d];
}

(function() {
  var a = 3,
    b = 5,
    c = 111;
  var [x, y, d] = solve_diophantine(a, b, c);
  console.log(`result: a*x+b*y=c: (${a}*${x} + ${b}*${y}) == ${a*x+b*y}`);
  console.assert((a * x + b * y) == c);

  // non-negative solutions if they exist
  // (-x * d / b) <= k <= (y * d / a)
  for (var k = Math.ceil(-x * d / b); k <= Math.floor(y * d / a); ++k) {
    var xx = x + k * b / d,
      yy = y - k * a / d;
    console.log(`result: a*x+b*y=c: (${a}*${xx} + ${b}*${yy}) == ${a*xx+b*yy}`);
    console.assert((a * xx + b * yy) == c);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы хотите решить, называется [линейным диофантовым уравнением](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#.D0.9B.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.B9.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.B4.D0.B8.D0.BE.D1.84.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2.D1.8B_.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F) и:

1. может быть неразрешимо (например, если вы хотите «разделить» 111 не на 5 и 3, а скажем, на 5 и 10).
2. если разрешимо — имеет бесконечно много решений в целых числах.

Алгоритмически, пожалуй, проще всего действовать подбором, хотя с точки зрения эффективности это, пожалуй, не лучший способ:

```
ax + by = с
```

Выбрать большее (чтоб считать меньше :)), скажем, это `a`, и для `x` от 0 до `c / a` (деление целочисленное) вычислять `c - ax` и смотреть, делится ли оно на `b`.

Comment: Перебирать можно от 0 до `b-1`. Среди бесконечного множества решений точно должно быть такое.