# Найти число B такое что A*B+A+B делится на N для заданных A и N

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

```
f = open("input.txt", "r")
z = open("output.txt", "w+")
F = f.read()
A, N = map(int, F.split())
B = 0
с = 0
for B in range(10**9):
    if (A * B + A + B) % N == 0:
        с = 1
        break
if c != 1:
    B = -1
z.write(str(B))
f.close()
z.close()
```

Даются два числа. A и N. Надо найти такое B, чтобы (AB+A+B)%N=0 (сумма произведения и суммы делится на N).
Ограничение по времени - одна секунда.
Перебор подходит только для малых чисел.
Если такого числа B нет, то выводим -1.

Как быстро проверить все числа B (B не больше 10**9)?

Comment: Я не совсем понял- найти надо все «В» удовлетворяющие формуле или одно?

Comment: Одно. Любое, которое подходит

Comment: Имхо, вы не правильно формулируете задачу - ваша задача не _быстро проверить все числа B_, а _ограничить возможные значения B так чтобы можно было быстро их перебрать_

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Можно решить быстро без перебора, просто за счёт нахождения обратного по модулю N числа.

Вначале переписываем выражение

```
A * B + A + B = 0 (mod N) 
         ⇓
(A + 1) * (B + 1) = 1 (mod N) 
         ⇓ 
B = (A + 1)^(-1) - 1 (mod N)
```

Потом используем для инверсии A + 1 [Расширенный Эвклидов Алгоритм](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), алгоритм работает почти мгновенно и не требует перебора.

Вот полный код на Питоне ([Запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/NB7B/2)):

```
def inverse(a, n):
    (t, newt, r, newr) = (0, 1, n, a)
    while newr != 0:
        quotient = r // newr
        (t, newt) = (newt, t - quotient * newt) 
        (r, newr) = (newr, r - quotient * newr)
    if r > 1:
        raise ValueError("a is not invertible")
    if t < 0:
        t = t + n
    return t

def main():
    # A * B + A + B = 0 (mod N) <=> (A + 1) * (B + 1) = 1 (mod N) <=> B = (A + 1)^(-1) - 1 (mod N)
    A = 10
    N = 997
    B = 0

    try:
        B = (inverse(A + 1, N) - 1) % N
    except ValueError:
        B = -1

    print(B)

main()
```

Сходимость алгоритма инверсии логарифмическая, т.е. если A, B, N примерно 2^k, тогда достаточно 2k+2 итерации максимум, т.е. максимум 66 итераций для 32-битного наибольшего числа. [Смотреть доказательство тут](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483118/proving-the-number-of-iterations-in-the-euclidean-algorithm).

Comment: Пока я разбирался с [формулами преобразования](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Equivalencies) вы уже готовый ответ написали :-) +1

Comment: Сколько в худшем случае потребуется итераций?

Comment: @Андрей Если A, B, N примерно 2^k, тогда достаточно 2k+2 итерации максимум, т.е. сходимость логарифмическая, т.е. максимум 66 итераций для 32-битного наибольшего числа. [Смотреть тут](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483118/proving-the-number-of-iterations-in-the-euclidean-algorithm)

Comment: Круто, спасибо!

Comment: @jfs Понял вашу мысль, тогда пожалуйста поправьте как правильно должно быть.

Comment: 1- не используйте голый `except: `(это к примеру Ctrl+C перехватывает). Лучше `except ValueError:` (поправьте ещё Inverse). 2- лучше следовать pep-8 соглашению по именам. Main -> main, Inverse -> inverse. 3- можно ещё явно упомянуть, что расширенный алгоритм Евклида помогает найти x, y такие что `a*x+b*y=gcd(a,b)` (соотношение Безе). `x = inverse(b, a)`. Связанный вопрос: [разбить число на сумму произведений его составляющих](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/732818/23044)

Comment: @jfs Кое-что поправил.