# Как найти два целых числа X1, X2 из формулы M=3*X1+4*X2 с помощью программы на Python?

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

У нас есть формула M=3*X1+4*X2 где М — случайное(Целое) число вводимое нами, а 
X1,X2(целые) неизвестные.

Comment: Так же, как и на бумаге с ручкой?

Comment: [вот как можно  диофантовы уравнения вида a⋅x + b⋅y = c решить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/733066/23044) (с кодом на javascript, но код очень простой)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Wolfram Alpha очень удобное [API](https://products.wolframalpha.com/api/). Установить [клиент](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wolframalpha) можно так `pip3 import wolframalpha`. С помощью него можно очень просто получить целочисленные решение вашего Диофантово уравнения.

```
import wolframalpha
query = "{}=3*X1+4*X2".format(input())
client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id) #app_id можно получить на сайте Wolfram Alpha API
results = list(client.query(query).pods)
print(results[6]['subpod']['plaintext']) #целочисленные решения в виде простого текста
```

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/pzEwcy

```
m = int(input())

x2 = m % 3
x1 = (m - 4 * x2) // 3

if x1 >= 0:
  print("{0} = 3*{1} + 4*{2}".format(m, x1, x2))
else:
  print("Нет неотрицательных решений")
```

Comment: Ваше решение находит только одно из бесконечного множества решений

Comment: @ЗвягинцевДенис, да, с минимальным неотрицательным x2.