# Задача "Диофантово уравнение"

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

> Даны три целых числа a, b, c (a > 0, b > 0). Нужно найти x и y такие, что ax + by = c (при этом нужно вынести в отдельную функцию нахождение наибольшего общего делителя по алгоритму Евклида (def gcd(a,b)) и расширенный алгоритм Евклида (extended_gcd(a, b))).

Мой вариант:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    assert a >= 0 and b >= 0 and a + b > 0

    while a > 0 and b > 0:
        if a >= b:
            a = a % b
        else:
            b = b % a
    return max(a, b)


def extended_gcd(a, b):
    q = gcd(a, b)
    if a > b:
        v = (a // b) + 1
        u = -1
    elif b > a:
        u = (b // a) + 1
        v = -1
    else:
        u = -q
        v = 2 * q
    return u, v, q


def diophantine(a, b, c):
    (u, v, q) = extended_gcd(a, b)
    x = u * (c // q)
    y = v * (c // q)
    return x, y
```

Нормально отрабатывает на этих входных данных:

```
print(diophantine(10, 6, 14))
print(diophantine(3, 6, 18))
print(diophantine(1, 1, 7))

(-7, 14) 
(18, -6) 
(-7, 14)
```

А вот здесь "ломается":

```
print(diophantine(15, 35, 20))

(12, -4)
```

Что я не учла?

Comment: Прекрасный код для PEP 8. +1.

Comment: Вы написала дважды тот-же самый тест (`print(diophantine(1, 1, 7))`) - первый раз не ломается, а второй - ломается?

Comment: Ой! не заметила, большое спасибо! исправила.

Comment: а разве что-то сломалось?
вроде все верно. 180 - 160 = 20.
.
Или последний блок - это не листинг, а "желание", а код "затыкается"?

Comment: 180 - 140 != 20 , к сожалению (((

Comment: связанный вопрос [разбить число на сумму произведений его составляющих](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/732818/23044)

Comment: @jfs благодаря Вашей подсказке про коэффициенты Безу все получилось!  Огромное Вам спасибо!)

Comment: @Lazarevna, вы теперь можете написать ответ на ваш собственный вопрос (и возможно получить за него баллы).

Answer (score 2):

благодаря подсказке [@jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs) [про коэффициенты Безу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732818/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85) получился вот такой рабочий код:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while a > 0 and b > 0:
        if a >= b:
            a = a % b
        else:
            b = b % a
    return max(a, b)


def extended_gcd(a, b):
    p = 1
    q = 0
    r = 0
    s = 1

    while a != 0 and b != 0:
        if a >= b:
            a = a - b
            p = p - r
            q = q - s
        else:
            b = b - a
            r = r - p
            s = s - q
    if a != 0:
        x = p
        y = q
    else:
        x = r
        y = s
    return x, y


def diophantine(a, b, c):
    (u, v) = extended_gcd(a, b)
    x = u * (c // gcd(a, b))
    y = v * (c // gcd(a, b))
    return x, y
```